# Delete tag content using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a long string in PHP, which contains few tables and word between them (HTML in string). I need to delete all tables with specific classes (fQuote) from it, but when i'm trying to use my regular expression, it selected all content between first table occurance to last closing table tag.

My Regular Expression:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<table\s[^>]*class=\"[^\"]*fQuote[^\"]*\"[^>]*>.*<\/table>\s?/ix','',$content);
```

My test string:

```
<table class="fQuote simple_table"><tbody><tr><td class="fQuoteUser"><img class="fQuoteAvatar" src="http://localhost/images/avatars/na.png" /><br /><a class="clear" href="http://localhost/user/1">User1</a></td><td class="fQuoteCorner"> </td><td class="fQuoteTable"><table class="default_table"><tbody><tr><td class="fQuoteBody">Some text</td></tr><tr><td class="fQuoteDate">Quoting a message <a class="clear fQuotedID" href="http://localhost/p/92">#9</a> 12 december 2011 23:43</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table><p>text needed to stay</p><table class="fQuote simple_table" style="width:932px"><tbody><tr><td class="fQuoteUser"><img class="fQuoteAvatar" src="http://localhost/images/avatars/na.png" /><br /><a class="clear" href="http://localhost/user/2">User2</a></td><td class="fQuoteCorner"> </td><td class="fQuoteTable"><table class="default_table" style="height:187px; width:830px"><tbody><tr><td class="fQuoteBody"><br />Quoted<br /><table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" style="height:34px; width:738px"><tbody><tr><td><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height:32px; width:736px"><tbody><tr><td><em><a class="main_normal" href="http://localhost/p/444" target="_blank">#444</a> <strong>User3</strong>15.12.2011 16:56<br />Some text2</em></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table><br /><br /><br />some text3</td></tr><tr><td class="fQuoteDate">Quoting a message <a class="clear fQuotedID" href="http://localhost/p/447">#22</a>  15 december 2011 16:33<br /></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I need delete everything from this conrecte test case except

```
<p>text needed to stay</p>
```

When i'm using my Regular Expression it's get first table openning tag and selecting everything until last table closing tag, which cutting phrase to stay and getting clear string in result.

Please help with correct regular expression. Thanks.

Comment: regex for test: http://rubular.com/r/zL2VJpaSER

Comment: You could try a negative lookahead on `.*` right before <\/table> saying that it should not match <\/table>. That might work

Comment: Which will be something like this i think: `(?!<\/table>).*`

Comment: Why not to use DOMDocument, it's reliable and gives exact result. Load your html, find the node and remove it. would be accurate.